# Write results of SQL query to multiple files based on field value

Tags: sql, db2

My team uses a query that generates a text file over 500MB in size.

The query is executed from a Korn Shell script on an AIX server connecting to DB2.

The results are ordered and grouped by a specific field.

My question: Is it possible, using SQL, to write all rows with this specific field value to its own text file?

For example: All rows with field VENDORID = 1 would go to 1.txt, VENDORID = 2 to 2.txt, etc.

The field in question currently has 1000+ different values, so I would expect the same amount of text files.

Comment: While exploring alternate solutions to this problem, I stumbled on a solution here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126209/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-based-on-the-content-into-multiple-text-files

I was investigating the use of a Perl script to split the large file and discovered that awk can do exactly what I'm looking for, given that my data is ordered and grouped.

This solution in question:
awk '{print >> substr($1,1,4)}' CAMS.TXT 

I plugged in the start and end character values of my vendor field, and specified my source file where 'CAMS.TXT' is located.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an alternative approach that gets each file directly from the database.**

You can use the [DB2 export command](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) to generate each file.  Something like this should be able to create one file :

```
db2 export to 1.txt of DEL select * from table where vendorid = 1
```

I would use a shell script or something like Perl to automate the execution of such a command for each value.

Depending on how fancy you want to get, you could just hardcode the extent of vendorid, or you could first get the list of distinct vendorids from the table and use that.

This method might scale a bit better than extracting one huge text file first.

Comment: By suggesting the use of automation to run this, does this mean I would have to run the entire query for each vendorid to get the associated text file?